# Displaying video using WebRTC in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am currently learning how to utilize WebRTC in javascript.
Here are the codes I wrote:

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header>
  <title>video and audio</title>
  <style>
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      min-height: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #video {
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #audio {
      height: 50%;
      width: 50%;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</header>
<body>
  <div id="video"></div>
  <div id="audio"></div>
</body>
<script src="WebRTC.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

**WebRTC.js**

```
const constraints = {audio: true, video: {width: 1280, height: 70}}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then (
  (mediaStream) => {
    console.log('success')
    const video = document.querySelector('#video');
    video.srcObject = mediaStream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = () => {video.play();}
  })
.catch (
  console.log('unsuccessful')
)
```

When I open it, it asks me permission to access my camera, and the console returns "successful." So I think that the code is working fine
However, the video is not displayed on the `<div id="video">`. I googled the solution, but I have come up with nothing yet. I would be appreciated it if you could help me find what I am missing here. Thank you very much.

Comment: This may or may not be relevant, but are you including WebRTC.js in your HTML file?

Comment: You don't need a library to use webrtc, @LakshyaRaj. OP, have you tried using an actual video element rather than just a plain div? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: just play after attaching the media link. that should work. Also you should make use of a adapter library for webrtc implementation which is useful for handling cross-browser issues.

Comment: @jmargolisvt that's not what I meant. The OP has two files, main.html and WebRTC.js. main.html includes main.js, but there's no reference of the WebRTC.js file in the question. However, I do agree with your second point about using a video tag.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj I see now. Sry, my bad! :)

Comment: @LakshyaRaj "WebRTC.js" is actually "main.js". I made a mistake when posting the question. I edited the question to prevent further confuse. Sorry:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you are using a `div` tag instead of a `video` tag.

Just use the video tag below.

```
<video id="video"></video>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to play video on your page, you need to use the `<video />` tag instead of plain `<div />`. So you just need to change

```html
<div id="video"></div>
<div id="audio"></div>
```

with

```html
<video autoplay="true"></video>
```

Your final code will be like this:

```js
const constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: {
    width: 1280,
    height: 70
  }
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(
    (mediaStream) => {
      console.log('success')
      const video = document.querySelector('video');
      video.srcObject = mediaStream;
      video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
        video.play();
      }
    })
  .catch(
    console.log('unsuccessful')
  )
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

video {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay="true"></video>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/SMAKSS/pen/RwJxjpb

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of `<div>` if you want to display the screen then you need to use the `<video>` tag.

```
<div id="video-div">
      <video id="video" controls="true" autoplay="true"></video> 
</div>
```